# How do you create cloudwatch alarms to reboot instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to use EC2 recover action in my account but I am unable to do so. Whenever I try to create an alarm with action to reboot EC2 instance it gives the following error:

> A system administrator must provision SWF permissions for your IAM
>   user so that the IAM user can perform this action.

Unfortunately I am the administrator here, and can't get this to work. My user has AmazonEC2FullAccess and CloudWatchFullAccess.

Docs say: 
`If you want to use an IAM role to stop, terminate, or reboot an instance using an alarm action, you can only use the EC2ActionsAccess role.`

But I don't know what should this role say? Couldn't find a sample role anywhere.

Refer: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/terraform-tool/N8s8MvFD_Rs

Comment: I think its in question only assign access to SWF and try it ?

Answer (score 2):

Need to add policy for you IAM user to allow access to the swf, something like this:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "swf:*"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Please note: swf doesn't support resource based restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
        "ec2:DescribeInstanceStatus",
        "ec2:DescribeInstances",
        "ec2:StopInstances",
        "ec2:TerminateInstances"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "*"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow"
    }
  ]
}
```

Note that according to [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html), "You can't assign a role to an existing instance; you can only specify a role when you launch a new instance."

Comment: I added a policy EC2ActionAccessPolicy with the above mentioned policy document and then created the EC2ActionsAccess role with the policy attached. I then launched a new instance with the role and tried created an alarm to reboot the instance, but no luck. :( It still gives me the following error:
A system administrator must provision SWF permissions for your IAM user so that the IAM user can perform this action.